# How to append an <i> tag to an <a> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append an  tag for an icon to an  tag using JQuery.

This is the code for how I am trying to append it:

```
$loginLink = $('ul.nav li:eq(2) a');
$loginLink.append("<i class='icon -login' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
```

For some reason, it does not work :(

JQuery is new to me so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *does not work* is `undefined`

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console? Have you tried using console.log to check if $loginLink selects the right elements?

Comment: can you share the dom.

Comment: On a first look, I see a space in the icon class. Remove the space and check it.

Comment: No there are no errors in the js console. $LoginLink does select the correct element as I am changing the text using JQuery: $loginLink.text("Account");

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help. Is the "space" between "icon" and "-login" a typo? Does it need to be "icon-login"?

By the way which library are you using? Is it the Icons by jQuery UI?

Comment: There is supposed to be a space inbetween. They are separate classes.No I am not using that library, just the standard jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$loginLink = $('ul.nav li:eq(2) a');
alert($loginLink.length); // must be different from 0 (just to be sure your selector is matching a dom element)

$newElement = $("<i>").html("myText")
                      .prop("aria-hidden","true")
                      .addClass("icon")
                      .addClass("-login") ;
$loginLink.append($newElement);
```

The point is to create a new  dom element using `$newElement = $('<i>')`.
After that you add properties and class as you want.
Finally, you append it to the container `$loginLink`.

Creating a new element let you remove it later if you need :

```
$newElement.detach(); // detach from dom, but still existing and can be re-appended.
```

or

```
$newElement.remove(); // detach and delete the element.
```

---

EDIT : you can also use the short method :

```
$loginLink.append($("<i>").html("myText")
                          .prop("aria-hidden","true")
                          .addClass("icon")
                          .addClass("-login")
                 );
```

Comment: The alert shows a value of 1. But the new element has not been appended to the <a> tag. This is very mind boggling.

Comment: I forgot the `$` for the append of the `newElement` when I first posted. I fixed the the solution. And I did a fiddle :  http://fiddle.jshell.net/2ws7A/

Comment: Yes, I noticed and I fixed it. But still the same result. Its really hard to tell since there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Did you notice the `eq()` selector is 0-indexing based ? Maybe you are looking the wrong  `li` ... have a look to my fiddle.

Comment: I am using 0-indexing aswell.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ? Report your HTML structure and your actual javascript... Will be simpler to investigate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52174/discussion-between-msieur-toph-and-nirali-patel)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/LDvTX/

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a>list item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>list item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>list item 3</a></li>
    <li><a>list item 4</a></li>
    <li><a>list item 5</a></li>
</ul>

$loginLink = $('ul.nav li:eq(2) a');
$loginLink.append("<i class='icon -login' aria-hidden='true'>HERE</i>");
```

Comment: This is exactly how I am doing it in my code but it doesn't seem to work like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

```
 $loginLink = $('ul.nav li:eq(2) a');
 $($loginLink).append("<i class='icon -login' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are the

tags previously dynamically generated ? What fire the actions ?

Comment: The action is fired based on checking if there is a cookie with a specific value.